# How can I programmatically generate Entity Framework classes from a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I programmatically generate Entity Framework classes from a database and then automatically compile them?

I'm looking for a solution that takes a simple connection string and generates a C# library. Exactly what Visual Studio's entity designer does but programmatically.

Comment: Did you find any ways to generate EF classes in database-first applications? After years actually!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [Entity Framework power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx).

With that you can create a code first database from a connectionstring (Reverse Engineer Code First ).

With Reverse Engineer Code First you get the code first classes + mapping classes. You can even modify the templates used for the process. All the information you need can be found in the above link.

Comment: This looks really good but it's a visual studio extension. Is there any way to Reverse Engineer Code First programmatically?

Comment: Not that I know. But why programmatically if I may ask? This is something you do once. What is your goal? Creating a tool that does this?

Comment: It looks like this visual studio extension is [open source](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/42370a831b55#src/PowerTools/Handlers/ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.cs). So this is exactly what I need. Thanks!